# Add nested object to json data in Mysql databse

Tags: mysql, json, nested-object

I tried a lot to add a nested object to my mysql column but it just add it as a new key. here is my sample:

```
{
    "Vocab": {
        "username":"132423424",

        "Mother": {
           "code":"1",
      "progress":"1",
      "nextdate":"22-10-2020",
 "lastcheck":"22-10-2020"
        },
        "Father": {
           "code":"2",
      "progress":"2",
      "nextdate":"22-10-2020",
       "lastcheck":"22-10-2020"
        } 
    }
}
```

I want to add this object with its inner keys under Vocab object:

```
   "Brother": {
           "code":"3",
      "progress":"1",
      "nextdate":"22-12-2020",
       "lastcheck":"22-12-2020"
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you make the second data also a valid JSON
Like

```
 {   "Brother": {
       "code":"3",
  "progress":"1",
  "nextdate":"22-12-2020",
   "lastcheck":"22-12-2020"
    } }
```

You use [JSON_MERGE_PATCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch)

> ```
> SET @a = '{
>     "Vocab": {
>         "username":"132423424",
>
>         "Mother": {
>            "code":"1",
>       "progress":"1",
>       "nextdate":"22-10-2020",
>  "lastcheck":"22-10-2020"
>         },
>         "Father": {
>            "code":"2",
>       "progress":"2",
>       "nextdate":"22-10-2020",
>        "lastcheck":"22-10-2020"
>         } 
>     }
> }';
> SET @b = '{   "Brother": {
>            "code":"3",
>       "progress":"1",
>       "nextdate":"22-12-2020",
>        "lastcheck":"22-12-2020"
>         } }';
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT JSON_MERGE_PATCH(@a, @b);
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSON_MERGE_PATCH(@a, @b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"Vocab": {"Father": {"code": "2", "nextdate": "22-10-2020", "progress": "2", "lastcheck": "22-10-2020"}, "Mother": {"code": "1", "nextdate": "22-10-2020", "progress": "1", "lastcheck": "22-10-2020"}, "username": "132423424"}, "Brother": {"code": "3", "nextdate": "22-12-2020", "progress": "1", "lastcheck": "22-12-2020"}} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3891b93501a86ed97f7fc7092511f2a5)*

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [`JSON_INSERT()`](https://database.guide/json_insert-insert-values-into-a-json-document-in-mysql/#:%7E:text=In%20MySQL%2C%20the%20JSON_INSERT(),by%20the%20value%20to%20insert.) function :

```
SET @data = '{
    "Vocab": {
        "username":"132423424",
        "Mother": {
        "code":"1",
        "progress":"1",
        "nextdate":"22-10-2020",
        "lastcheck":"22-10-2020"
        },
        "Father": {
        "code":"2",
        "progress":"2",
        "nextdate":"22-10-2020",
        "lastcheck":"22-10-2020"
        } 
    }
}';

SET @data2 = '{ "code": "3", "progress":"1", "nextdate":"22-12-2020", "lastcheck":"22-12-2020" }';


SELECT JSON_PRETTY(
          REPLACE( 
                 REPLACE(
                         REPLACE(
                                 JSON_INSERT(@data, '$.Vocab.Brother', (@data2))
                                ,'\\"','"')
                         ,'"{','{') 
                ,'}"','}') ) AS 'New JSON';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fcf55c8fa17632e98602a7d1acb9ae10)</kbd>

Using `REPLACE()` functions are needed at the end in order to format related to double-quotes.